# $\mathbf C\mathbf a\mathbf t$ as a concrete category

Tags: ct.category-theory

Consider the category **Cat** as a *concrete category* over **Set** $\times$ **Set** via the functor 
*U* : **Cat** $\rightarrow$ **Set** $\times$ **Set**, defined by

*U*$(\mathbf A \xrightarrow{F} \mathbf B) = ($*Ob*$(\mathbf A)\xrightarrow{F_O}$ *Ob*$(\mathbf B)$ , *Mor*$(\mathbf A)\xrightarrow{F_M}$ *Mor*$(\mathbf B))$,

where $F_O$ is the restriction of $F$ to objects and $F_M$ is its restrictions to morphisms.

**Cat** is the category of all *small* categories in the sense that their *objects* and *morphisms* form sets (not classes).

It is clear that this *concrete category* is *transportable*. **But is this category uniquely transportable?**

<sub>A concrete category $(\mathbf A, U)$ over $\mathbf X$ is said to be **(uniquely) transportable** provided that for every $\mathbf A-$object A and every $\mathbf X-$isomorphism $UA\xrightarrow{k}X$ there exists a (unique) $\mathbf A-$object B with $UB=X$ such that $A\xrightarrow{k}B$ is an $\mathbf A-$isomorphism.</sub>

Comment: For all I know, the collocation "concrete category over $\mathbf{Set}\times\mathbf{Set}$" in this OP is very unusual. The term 'concrete category' is very usual of course, but that just means 'category $\mathsf{C}$ such that there is a faithful functor to $\mathsf{Set}$. (Cf. e.g. Riehl 2014, Def. 1.6.17) Would you mind explaining where you get this usage from?

Comment: Data point for those who would like to write an answer: in [J. Adámek,J. Rosický,E. M. Vitale: *Algebraic Theories: A Categorical Introduction to General Algebra*. Cambridge University Press 2011], Example 13.17.2 gives the *category $\Sigma$-Alg* of all '$\Sigma$-algebras' (perhaps not needless to say for some readers, these are not the '$\sigma$-algbras' of measure theory) as *an example of a uniquely-transportable concrete category*.

Comment: I'd say the answer is obviously 'yes', since the source, target, identity, and composition data that lift $X = (O, M)$ to a category structure (rendering $k$ an isomorphism of categories) is uniquely determined by "conjugating" the category structure on $A$ by the data of $k$. If this is not enough of a hint, then I guess I could write out the answer.

Comment: @ToddTrimble, yes, if you can provide an answer, i will be grateful.

Comment: @PeterHeinig, I took this usage from “Abstract and Concrete Categories” book. There you will find the notion of concrete category over an arbitrary category $\mathbf X$ if underlying functor is faithful.

Comment: @A.Gonus: I was recently told by someone knowing more than me about this that the A.C.C. book has quite a few unusual definitions.

Comment: While The Joy of Cats may have idiosyncrasies, I wouldn't consider this one of them. The usage here is immediately understandable and sensible.

Comment: How is this notion more useful than mere concreteness? Am I correct in reading the definition as "the faithful functor that testifies concreteness is an isofibration"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $X = (O, M)$ be a pair of sets, and let $A$ be a category with set of objects $O_A$ and set of morphisms $M_A$. Suppose given a pair $k = (k_0, k_1)$ of isomorphisms $k_0: O_A \to O$, $k_1: M_A \to M$. Let $s_A, t_A: M_A \to O_A$ be the source and target functions for $A$; then the only way to define the source and target functions $s, t: M \to O$ on the lifted structure over $X$ in such a way that $k$ preserves source and target data is by setting

$$s = k_0 \circ s_A \circ k_1^{-1}, \qquad t = k_0 \circ t_A \circ k_1^{-1}$$

(that's what I meant by "conjugating" in my comment).

It's the same idea to define the lifted structure $i, c$ for identity and composition. If $i_A, c_A$ are the identity and composition on $A$ and $k$ is to preserve identity and composition data, then there's only one way to define them: put

$$i = k_1 \circ i_A \circ k_0^{-1}, \qquad c = [(f, g) \mapsto (k_1 \circ c_A)(k_1^{-1} f, k_1^{-1} g)]$$

where $f, g$ is any composable pair in the lifted source-target structure over $X$.

Of course unique transport of structure via conjugation is a simple idea which applies much more generally, as hinted in Peter's second comment.

Comment: +1 for the last paragraph.